# Hadoop Mapreduce code with parseDouble giving exception in one system, but runs fine in other?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop Mapreduce code in Java. It works fine in my system, but when I try to run the same program in someone else's system (the final system on which it needs to be run) then it gives the following error. The error is supposedly in `line 81` where there is Double.parseDouble() command. It runs perfectly on my system. What may be the problem?

```
13/06/25 12:07:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
13/06/25 12:07:05 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/06/25 12:07:05 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/06/25 12:07:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306101543_0158
13/06/25 12:07:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/25 12:07:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/06/25 12:07:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
13/06/25 12:07:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :     attempt_201306101543_0158_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at Transpose$Reduce.reduce(Transpose.java:89)
    at Transpose$Reduce.reduce(Transpose.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

attempt_201306101543_0158_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201306101543_0158_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
13/06/25 12:07:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/06/25 12:07:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
13/06/25 12:07:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :     attempt_201306101543_0158_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at Transpose$Reduce.reduce(Transpose.java:89)
    at Transpose$Reduce.reduce(Transpose.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Relevant code (complete Reduce function)

```
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text mult = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            HashMap<Integer, String> mMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            HashMap<Integer, String> mMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

            for(Text value : values){
                String[] line = value.toString().split(",", 3);

            Integer row = Integer.valueOf(line[1]);

            if(line[0].equals("M")){
                mMap.put(row, line[2]);
            }
            else if(line[0].equals("Mt")){
                mMap1.put(row, line[2]);
            }       
        }

        double sum=0.0;

            for(Integer i=1; i<=mMap.size(); i++){
    String val1 = mMap.get(i);
    String val2 = mMap1.get(i);                

            double mij = Double.parseDouble(val1);
    double mjk = Double.parseDouble(val2);

    sum += mij*mjk;
            }
        String str = Double.toString(sum);
        mult.set(str);    
            context.write(key, mult);  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` thrown from `Double.parseDouble(String s)` which [happens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) if `s` is `null`. So, it sounds like you have some `null` input in your data on your "production" machine that doesn't reside on your "development" machine.

Comment: I would add that maybe you can add a check for `null` and perhaps create an empty `String` in that situation.  Or if an empty `String` is an issue to the parser, then perhaps have some sort of other functionality when having the case of a `null` `String`.

Comment: The data is exactly the same as it was in the development machine.

Comment: So I figured that the mapper is giving incorrect output on the production machine, and it is.
`String keyMt = Integer.toString(i) + "," + row_i`

Comment: I'll just post another question, this isn't helping